# How to create @FormDataParam dynamically for dynamic file uploads

Tags: file-upload, jersey, jax-rs, form-data

I just need to receive multiple image or file with some text data from client side to server. I am using java restful web services with spring hibernate integration. My controller is like..

```
@Path("/receiveFiles")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String receiveFile(@FormDataParam("file1") InputStream f1, @FormDataParam("file2") InputStream f2 ){
    UtilityMethods.saveImageFile(f1, "fileName.png");
    return null;
}
```

My front end is html,css and java script. so the file can be uploaded through FormData() but the receiving side is a problem. I just need a solution to get files dynamically at same request. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have solved this using [resteasy-multipart-provider](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.19.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html); this is not RestEasy-specific, it implements a JAXRS provider that can be plugged to any JAXRS (2.x I believe) implementation. I do not know a way to accomplish it with plain JAXRS.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos can you post some code???

Comment: I found that the only way I could reliably generate Java classes with annotations at runtime was with groovy.